# htaccess redirect from small to caps

Tags: .htaccess

can someone suggest, facing lot of duplication url issue in joomla

A) Facing issue in News Section

```
 Correct url- www.xyz.com/?page=11&&option=com_latestnews&view=list&Itemid=25
 Wrong url-   www.xyz.com/?page=11&&option=com_latestnews&view=list&itemid=25
```

If you see above, in word **Itemid**, i is small in wrong url and in caps I in correct url

B) Facing second issue in News Section

```
     Correct url- www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_latestnews&view=detail&n_id=365&Itemid=10
     Incorrect url-  www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_latestnews&view=detail&n_id=365&Itemid=25
```

If you see above, in word **Itemid**, the correct url is 10 but incorrect duplicate url is 25

how to get this corrected through .htaccess 301 redirect of duplicate pages created, any suggestion will be a saviour

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case with the **I** in `Itemid` you have to address that specifically. Then for all of the duplicate item ID's, you have to address explicitly.

Case issue:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)itemid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1Itemid=%2 [L,R=301]
```

For each from item ID:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&Itemid=25(&|$)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&Itemid=10&%3 [L,R=301]
```

Here, ID **25** gets redirected to **10**. You can add any additional ID's for the rest of your duplicated.